# Same window opening 2 times, while I click on option to open that window again

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on angular and as per requirements, I am following below steps:

1. Click on let's say x button, a new child window opens up.
2. Now while it is still loading, I click on x button again.
3. This time it should take me to already opening child window, but it is opening a new window, so now I have 2 same windows opening.

Can anyone help me with this issue.

I tried several options mentioned with window.open() and it parameters but that didn't work.